# Matching scientists and topics with certain restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are 999 scientists. Every 2 scientists are both interested in exactly 1 topic and for each topic there are exactly 3 scientists that are interested in that topic. Prove that it is possible to choose 250 topics such that every scientist is interested in at most 1 theme.

**Attempt:** The configuration is known as a Steiner triple system $S(2,3,999)$ (block design theory). Steiner triple systems $S(2,3,n)$ exist if and only if $n\equiv 1,3 \pmod{6}$, and since $999\equiv 3 \pmod{6}$, such a design exists. The number of topics (triples) must be $333\cdot 499$, and each scientist is interested in $499$ topics.

**Attempt - solution:** Decompose a $K_{999}$ into edge disjoint triangles. Prove that we can find $250$ vertex disjoint triangles.

We use extremal principle, i.e. take a configuration with maximal triangles who are vertex disjoint (I'll use a * every time I reference maximal triangles). Let us have $t$ triangles, where $t = 249$. Let the sets of vertices of our triangles be $T_i = \{a_i, b_i, c_i\}$ for $1 \le i \le t$. Let $X$ be the union of the $T_i$, and let $Y$ be the other $999-3t$ vertices not part of a $T_i$. Note that we cannot have any triangles with vertices solely in $Y$ (*). Consequently, for every edge between 2 vertices in $Y$, the third vertex completing the triangle must lie in $X$. Now for each point in $X$ we look at how it forms triangles with 2 other vertices in $Y$.

Now look at the set $T_i$. Assume that $a_i, b_i$ form triangles with the edges $ef, gh$ (all in $Y$) Then we can form more triangles, by deleting $T_i$ and forming the triangles $\{a_i, e, f\}$ and $\{b_i, g, h\}$ contradiction, by maximality (*). We'll call this result (**). We now show that form each $T_i$, the total number of edges in $Y$ that vertices in $T_i$ can form is $|Y|/2$. Assume WLOG firstly that both $a_i$, $b_i$ make triangles, otherwise its trivial. Note that $a_i$ can form at most $|Y|/2$ triangles with an edge in $Y$, and that those are edge disjoint, and therefore share no vertices in $Y$. Assume that for $a_i$, it forms triangles with the edges $ef, gh, ij$. Then all triangles formed by $b_i$ must touch both of these edges (**), impossible. Now say $a_i$ makes triangles with only 2 of these edges, but all triangles formed by $b_i$ must touch both of these edges, so that's only 4 more triangles. Same for $c_i$. So in total, we can get at most $2 + 4 = 6$ triangles. Similarly, we can now assume that for all vertices $a_i. b_i, c_i$ they form only one triangle, so at most 3. So we can now assume that only $a_i$ forms triangles, giving at most $|Y|/2$. To finish, we just count edges. We must use up all the edges, so looking at all $t$ groups, $t(|Y|/2) > \binom{|Y|}{2} \implies 249 = t >  |Y|-1 = 251$, contradiction. So we still have edges left, so we can add more triangles.

I don’t know if I’m correct, and I’d like a more complete and elegant solution than my approach

Comment: Is a "theme" a standard term?

Comment: @JohnDouma That's just part of the flavor text. (Theme = topic)